# Pydantic specify exceptions to route them to log

Tags: python, pydantic, python-logging

I've a question about Pydantic and im currently lost.
My wish is to create a list of valid Pydantic objects. This is based on if all the information is validated an correct. If there is a error in the validation, i wish to route it to the logging module of python, so that i get a log message stating that there was a error in the validation and that the particular object is skipped.

This is the current code that i created:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator, ValidationError
import re


class Employee(BaseModel):
    Employee_id: str = Field(alias='Employee number')
    Username: str
    Surname: str
    Firstname: str = Field(alias='First name')
    Role: str

    @validator('Employee_id', pre=True)
    def valid_employeeid(cls, employee_id_value):
        pattern = re.compile("\d\d\d\d\d\d")
        if not pattern.match(employee_id_value):
            if employee_id_value == "":
                raise ValueError("Empty mployee ID")
            else:
                raise ValueError("Not a valid employee ID")
        return employee_id_value


employees = [
    {
        "Employee number": "118791",
        "Username": "john.wick",
        "Surname": "Wick",
        "First name": "John",
        "Role": "Shooter"
    },
    {
        "Employee number": "118792",
        "Username": "james.bond",
        "Surname": "Bond",
        "First name": "James",
        "Role": "Agent"
    },
    {
        "Employee number": "118g93",
        "Username": "jack.reacher",
        "Surname": "Reacher",
        "First name": "Jack",
        "Role": "Shooter"
    }
]


pydan_obj = {}
for employee_id in employees:
    try:
        Employee_data = Employee(**employee_id)
        pydan_obj.update({employee_id["Employee number"]: Employee_data})
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
print(f"Created {len(pydan_obj)} objects")
```

In this situation, I've 3 employees that i want to add to the pydan_obj dict under their employee numbers. I only want to add employees with valid 'Employee numbers', so in this example jack reacher should be skipped, because his Employee number is not all digits.

The output at this moment is:

```
1 validation error for Employee
Employee number
  Not a valid employee ID (type=value_error)
Created 2 objects
```

The 'pydan_obj' contains only two employees, which is as intended, but what i want is to write a log message that 'jack reacher' was skipped with the reason.

My questions are:
First: I've created a logging handler, but im not sure where to init or place it in the above code.

Second: The current except captures each validation error. I would like to separate this in more possibilities. For example if a add a validator for the Surname, i would like to give this a custom Exception that creates a different log message.

Last: I would like to create a list of employees this way. This example only has 3 people in it, but in my case i would like to expand to 1000-2000 employees. Is this the way to go, or is there a different method to keep the objects? I need to keep them throughout the script runtime, because i need the information at different occasions.

Best regards and thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Great Questions.

1. Here's how you would instrument logging in general *(using [module level logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html))*:

```py
import logging

# Instantiate the logger by name
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Now log something
logger.info("this is a message")
```

2. Here's how logging (with error handling) would work in your solution:

> A note on error handling: When your validator function fails, it raises a `ValidationError` which is a collection of errors. You are trying to match the specific errors in the `ValidationError`. I provided a way for you to do that, although it is a bit tricky.

```py
import logging
import re

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator, ValidationError


# Instantiate logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Create custom exceptions
class InvalidEmployeeId(ValueError):
    ...


class EmptyEmployeeId(ValueError):
    ...



class Employee(BaseModel):
    Employee_id: str = Field(alias='Employee number')
    Username: str
    Surname: str
    Firstname: str = Field(alias='First name')
    Role: str


    @validator('Employee_id')
    def valid_employeeid(cls, value):
        pattern = re.compile("\d\d\d\d\d\d")

        if not pattern.match(value):
            # Raise these specific errors, but you can raise others
            if value == "":
                raise EmptyEmployeeId("Empty employee ID")
            else:
                raise InvalidEmployeeId("Not a valid employee ID")
        return value

employees = [
   ...
]


# I renamed some of the variables to make more sense
pydantic_objects = {}

for employee_record in employees:
    # Try creating an employee object
    try:
        employee_obj = Employee.parse_obj(employee_record)

        # Assign to your dict
        pydantic_objects[employee_obj.Employee_id] = employee_obj

    # If validation failed, check for specific errors
    # by entering the validation error context, then raising
    # "child" errors. (Alternatively, you can compare the error
    # context and match the class name.) The reason this is a bit
    # complicated is because Pydantic is migrating to a rust backend
    # where the validations are performed in rust: https://docs.pydantic.dev/blog/pydantic-v2/#validator-function-improvements
    except ValidationError as validation_error:

        try:
            # Raise the "child" errors from the parent
            for e in validation_error.raw_errors:
                raise (e.exc)

        except InvalidEmployeeId:
            logger.warning(
                f"Skipping this record (records={employee_record}) "
                "EmployeeID is not a valid ID"
            )

        except EmptyEmployeeId:
            logger.warning(
                f"Skipping this record (records={employee_record}) "
                "EmployeeID is an empty string."
            )

        # If it fails for a reason you didn't specify, halt the program
        except Exception as e:
            logger.warning("This is a different warning we didn't catch")
            raise Exception(e)


print(f"Created {len(pydantic_objects)} objects")
```

3. This solution would indeed scale with many employees, though you probably want to store the "bad records" in another object so you can perhaps export them, or do additional processing. You probably also want to report some metrics on how much of your data was good or not.